# How can I use sed and grep to fix my file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file with firstname.lastname and want to grab a specific number of letters from lastname and then append first initial behind that for each line in the file.  example below

john.williams needs to be changed to willij

Comment: See [ask] then try again.

Comment: Try this ```echo "john.williams" | sed -e 's/\(.\{1\}\).*\.\(.\{5\}\).*/\2\1/' -```

Comment: how would be done if the names are in a file named test?

Comment: Also does that take int account that some names are longer or shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$ cat test
john.williams
john.doe
jane.doe
lois.lane
$ sed -e 's/\(.\{1\}\).*\.\(.\{1,5\}\).*/\2\1/' test
willij
doej
doej
lanel
$
```

Explanation below :

```
substitute the following 

\(.\{1\}\)    The very first character, capture it   
.*            Followed by other characters  
\.            Followed by a .  
\(.\{1,5\}\)  Followed by upto 5 characters, capture them  
.*            Followed by other characters  

with this 

\2\1          Print the second capture sequence followed by the first sequence
```